# It became clear to me

Tags: adverbs

Why, if clear describes the way in which "it" became more obvious, so we use an adjective (clear) instead of an adverb (clearly)?

Comment: Many verbs take adjectives, not adverbs.

Answer (score 2):

**To become** is a true *linking* verb (like *to be*), so it only takes an adjective, a noun or a pronoun (to become *what or having what quality?*) as its *subject complement*.

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm

The action of that verb cannot be modified by an adverb (that's what adverbs typically do): you cannot put a question 'become how?' If you take a transitive verb 'to explain' and use it with a direct object, e. g.

> I explained the matter.

you'll be able to modify its action, aimed at that object,  with an adverb:

> I explained the matter clear**ly**.

Compare it with the case where *to make* is used as a *linking* verb:

> I made it clear.

Comment: The action of that verb can certainly be adverbially modified:  It quickly became clear.  It eventually became clear.  It unfortunately became clear.  It simply became clear.  There's nothing strange, let alone impossible, about the question "how did it become clear?"

Comment: It is true that adverbs can be _applied_ to the verb _to become_, but it looks like they only modify _outer conditions_ for its action (like time of action, easiness to perform it, doubts and expectations about the fact of action, etc. - like 'it clearly became something'). But the action of that verb remains the same: it's about the fact of _changing a state_ specified by its _subject compliment_ which can't be an adverb or adverbial phrase.